# Authenticate an user with Keycloak calling a Webservice

Tags: web-services, oauth-2.0, saml, keycloak, openid-provider

I'm trying to secure a connection to a Java EE webapp using Keycloak.
Beeing completly new to Keycloak, and how to configure it, I would like to do this :

1. When trying to reach my webapp without beeing authenticated, I am redirected to Keycloak login page (this is done)
2. I enter login / password, and I want Keycloak to call a WS who will check my DB if this user exists, and will return a specified data to Keycload, if user found, to be used in the webapp when connected. (**This is what I don't know**)

I saw that we might use an "id provider" in Keycloak admin console, but I don't know if I have to use "SAML" or "Opend ID Connect" for start, and how to configure this ("authorization URL", "Token URL", "Client ID", "Client Secret")

Can someone help me on this please? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll probably need to write your own user federation provider, to retrieve the users from your endpoint. See this part of the docs: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_user-storage-federation Also, take care of securing your user retrieval endpoint, otherwise anybody will be able to access it.